# how to debug boot receiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have the following Reciever and I get an app crash on device boot.

Since it happens on boot I cannot attach the debug via eclipse nor see anything in the logcat.

How would you suggest for me to see the error causing the crash?

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent != null) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

                if (action != null) {
                    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                        // GeoPushService geoPs = new GeoPushService();
                        ZoomerLocationService locService = new ZoomerLocationService();

                        locService.startService(new Intent());

                        // Log.d("receiver","action is: boot");
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding this try-catch

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent != null) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            try {
                if (action != null) {
                    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
                        // GeoPushService geoPs = new GeoPushService();
                        ZoomerLocationService locService = new ZoomerLocationService();

                        locService.startService(new Intent());

                        // Log.d("receiver","action is: boot");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(MyLogger.TAG, ex.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't help

I have tried to send BOOT_COMPLETE intent and i got permissions denial

Comment: Can't you can trigger the receiver yourself by sending an intent with action set to Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED ? The environment won't be completely the same, but for a first try it should suffice.

Comment: @Kedarnath not Log.e ? what do you mean?

Comment: @Su-AuHwang I have tried to send BOOT_COMPLETE intent and i got permissions denial

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use ADB in a command line to record the logcat when your device is booting up.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Command-Option-Log-Buffer.html

Make sure to increase the amount of data the command window can display or else use the options to save the log to a file.

Using this method you might be able to see the crash in the log on startup.

EDIT: I have tried this and it is possible, this should work for you